# Cuba intercity bus tickets - book in advance vs on spot

Tags: buses, cuba, havana

- Should I book Viazul bus tickets on Viazul.com in advance?
- There are not so many departure times - can tickets be sold out if I will come to a bus station and will try to buy a ticket few hours before
  departure?
- Is it possible to reserve a ticket in a station for a
  route which is between different cities than station?

There is similar question about [Intercity transportation in Cuba](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/87106/intercity-transportation-in-cuba) but it is more about specific routes and Viazul alternatives - *taxi colectivos*.

Comment: I know it but is does not answer my question.

Comment: Answers to your questions: yes, yes, no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found info on [Cuba - Get around - Viazul](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Cuba):

> Reservations can be made in advance on their website, but this is
>   typically only necessary when leaving from or going to popular
>   destinations in high season. Reservations can also be made at a Viazul
>   ticket office (usually located at or near the place where the buses
>   stop). If the bus is full, it’s very likely that you’ll be offered a
>   ride in share taxi for the same price as the bus. If there are no
>   shared taxis going to your destination, the ticket salesperson will
>   likely advise you to arrive half an hour before the time of departure
>   and wait for a late cancelation. If there is a late cancelation, you
>   will be allowed to purchase a 'ticket' from the bus driver.

[Tips for independent travellers to Cuba](https://www.theguardian.com/travel/2016/apr/30/cuba-travel-tips):

> Many routes are oversubscribed. If your travel plans aren’t fixed,
>   turn up early at the station and join the queue.