# Cuba 'taxi colectivo' - availability and prices?

Tags: taxis, cuba, havana

- How long may it take to find/wait for a *taxi colectivo* for intercity routes (for example from Varadero Airport to Havana city)?
- Does it usually wait to collect a full car before departing?
- How much does it cost?
- Does it differ from Viazul bus ticket price if car takes four people?

Comment: Some of the answers to your question can be obtained from [comments here](http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/87112/42757)

Comment: Every time I visit my parents in Havana I go through Varadero and take a taxi (is usually cheaper that a direct flight). Piece of advice: if your flight is arriving after 10pm, you may have a hard time finding a taxi, and when you do, it's going to be way more expensive than during the day. In such cases it might be better if you can arrange for someone to pick you up.

Comment: I will be in Varadero at 16:05. The last Viazul is at 18:20 but they are sold out for my arrival date.

Comment: At that time it will be fairly easy to catch a taxi, just ask to one of the guards at the exit door and they will be happy to help (they get a small commission on every customer they bring in).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Tips for independent travellers to Cuba](https://www.theguardian.com/travel/2016/apr/30/cuba-travel-tips):

> If you can’t get a seat, persistent private taxi drivers (boteros)
>   outside all bus stations will gather up travellers and charge them the
>   same as or less than Víazul. It’s a door-to-door service but nervous
>   passengers should be aware that they drive like the wind.

**UPDATE**

It shouldn't be a problem to get *taxi colectivo* during the daytime after flight. They may ask $20-$25 per person from Varadero airport to Havana.

*taxi colectivo* are also available in other cities near Viazul station. You may also talk with *casa particular* owners or people offering taxi service in the city center. The best time to get it is related to Viazul timetable. Know the prices and be ready to negotiate. I have paid $8 for Cienfuegos - Trinidad (Viazul costs $6), $20 for Santa Clara - Havana (Viazul $18), $20 for Havana - Vinales (Viazul $12, at first we agreed for $15 but later they raised price).

If you want book a Viazul ticket 1 or 2 days before departure, they may say that tickets are sold out. In this case, if you are travelling solo or not in a big group come to Viazul station 30 min before departure - there are not many seats left but I had success buying tickets this way. Otherwise, take *taxi colectivo*.